# Select edge with both vertices from SQL db storing a graph structure

Tags: sql, graph, sqlite

I have two tables to store graph data.

Vertex table:

```
+----+---+---+
| id | x | y |
+----+---+---+
```

And the edge table (many-to-many relationship):

```
+---------+-------+
| from_id | to_id |
+---------+-------+
```

I want to select all edges with the corresponding vertices like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

where x1 and y1 are the coordinates of the source vertex and x2 and y2 are the coordinates of the destination vertex.

What is the corresponding SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT v_from.x x1, 
       v_from.y y1,
       v_to.x   x2,
       v_to.y   y2
FROM edge AS e
JOIN vertex AS v_from
  ON e.from_id = v_from.id
JOIN vertex AS v_to
  ON e.to_id = v_to.id
```